# Why is first for loop iteration skipped?

Tags: java

my code is yielding an unexpected result. It seems my for loop skips the first iteration and I don't understand why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;

    // Ex.1.

    String family_name;
    String[] family_array;

    System.out.println("Enter number of family members: ");
    number = get.nextInt();
    family_array = new String[number];

    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter family member name: ");
        family_name = get.nextLine();
        family_array[i] = family_name;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        System.out.println(family_array[i]);
    }

}
```

Returns... (pretend the number input are names)

```
Enter number of family members: 
5
Enter family member name: 
Enter family member name: 
1
Enter family member name: 
2
Enter family member name: 
3
Enter family member name: 
4

1
2
3
4
```

Why is the first get.nextLine() skipped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently your call to [Scanner#nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) is not consuming the newline character so it is being passed through to your first call of `Scanner#nextLine`, therefore it does *not* block.

You will need to add

```
get.nextLine();
```

after calling `nextInt` so that your first call to `nextLine` will block for `IO`.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that blank line between 4 and 1?

```
4
       //this is it
1
```

When you call get.NextInt() you'd not eating the whole line, just the next int. The empty rest of the line is eaten in your first loop iteration. Add a call to get.nextLine() after reading the int.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was instantiating a new `Scanner` in each iteration:

```
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter family member name: ");

    Scanner loopGet = new Scanner(System.in);
    family_name = loopGet.nextLine();
    family_array[i] = family_name;
}
```

Comment: i thought it wasn't probably the best technique but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    number = get.nextInt();
     // if i enter 4 then it will 4\n and nextInt will take only 4 
     // and the \n will be taken as input by the getline.
    get.nextLine();  
     //this will return the "" from ""\n . so adding this will solve your problem
    family_array = new String[number];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to say it is because you still have a buffered CR/LF - so the first one is set to blank. Notice the blank line as you print your family names (numbers).  That is your blank family name.

The keyboard input is a buffered stream - it has your 5, and it has a CR/LF (or perhaps just a LF, depending on your OS).

You probably want to get the LINE and then do a string.convert, atoi, system.convert (whichever one is for Java) to get the #.